# google task api only insert taskList get Quota Exceeded

Tags: google-tasks

I am using Google Tasks API in php for managing my lists and tasks but recently I am having a problem with inserting a new task list, the point is that all the other calls are working correctly.

Any suggestions to resolve the error?

So I try to be as clear as possible.
1- the script I am using is the one pointed to by the endpoint, I simply call the endpoint with the parameters I provided.
2- I interface with the API tasks for a complete management of my tasks so list, create, edit and delete tasklist and ist, create, edit and delete tasks. All calls work except the create tasklist which returns the Quota Exceeded error.
I checked the limits on the google console but they are not even at 10%. Also to make the problem even more difficult to understand is that if I try to make the call with a different account it works correctly. So in short, the error occurs exclusively on the create tasklist with a certain email address.

I hope that my problem is well explained.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the error?

Comment: Sure you can find the source here [https://github.com/soury/googletasks]
to do a test see readme.md or readme1.md the call that gives the problem is the creation of task list.

Comment: here is the error returned: {  "result": false,  "message": "{         \"error\": {             \"code\": 403,             \"message\": \"Quota Exceeded\",             \"errors\": [                   {                     \"message\": \"Quota Exceeded\",                 \"domain\": \"usageLimits\",                 \"reason\": \"quotaExceeded\"               }             ]         }     }" }

Comment: Can you provide the script being used?

Comment: the call is as follows:
`http://localhost/google-tasks-api/api1.php/task-lists/`
` {
  "title": "Prova Sora"
 }`
but by logging in with another account I saw that it works correctly.
So I really don't know where the problem is ‍

Comment: Sorry, but you can provide the script being used, without it it's difficult to determine what the error is.

Comment: Here is the call that returns the error: [http://task-api.bfstridegroup.com/api1.php/task-lists/]

Comment: The script, not the response

Comment: POST [http://task-api.bfstridegroup.com/api1.php/task-lists/]
` {
  "title": "Prova Sora"
 }`

Comment: Sorry if I have not explained myself well, could you provide the script you are using? Not the endpoint of your application. Also could you explain what this means: `the point is that all the other calls are working correctly.`

Comment: I'll get back to you with an answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the API documentation for [Google Tasks API Pricing and Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/tasks/pricing#:%7E:text=The%20Google%20Tasks%20API%20has,of%20the%20Google%20APIs%20Console.):

> The Google Tasks API has a courtesy limit of 50,000 queries per day. If you need capacity beyond this courtesy limit, you can send a request from the [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard#:quotas) pane of the Google APIs Console.

Comment: I have already checked the limits but I am far from achieving. in any case if I had reached the limit this would do for all calls and not just for the creation of a new list.